pipe payload of redis stream retrieved using redis-cli to decompression utility
We are using redis streams as a messaging middleware between two processes.
We typically have a single key "event", and the value is a json payload.
XADD stream * "event" "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", ... }" 

Lately, as we have scaled, we have found the memory requirement for our redis server is becoming quite large.
I've been running some tests where I compress the payload, which results in a payload size of ~10% of the uncompressed size.
The problem:
One of the tools we use to debug issues is redis-cli.
In the old regime, running redis-cli would result in an output similar to the following:
$ redis-cli XRANGE test.stream - + COUNT 3
1) 1) "1722441037024301192-0"
   2) 1) "event"
      2) "{ \"time\": \"2024-07-31 15:50:37.024200355\", \"data\": \"fttKY6Y6DGvbpjHTw9YxrxNUd8zEbA3f12DGVGL7PiCRQ5wb24\" }"
2) 1) "1722441038024875918-0"
   2) 1) "event"
      2) "{ \"time\": \"2024-07-31 15:50:38.024695189\", \"data\": \"MfP8JvPZmNPAtKXk1v5X37cod5x67ChX6o22k5IDShbJZ4cjlI\" }"
3) 1) "1722441039025362443-0"
   2) 1) "event"
      2) "{ \"time\": \"2024-07-31 15:50:39.025331292\", \"data\": \"zEx5rPzy10ASbVRFIfyRV9B3YQ34cDvkmRcCWhUWBDwqrANpLJ\" }"

A workflow we've become used to is to grep for a field we know is present in the payload (eg: "time") and then pipe the result to jq
$ redis-cli XRANGE test.stream - + COUNT 3 | grep time | jq
{
  "time": "2024-07-31 15:50:37.024200355",
  "data": "fttKY6Y6DGvbpjHTw9YxrxNUd8zEbA3f12DGVGL7PiCRQ5wb24"
}
{
  "time": "2024-07-31 15:50:38.024695189",
  "data": "MfP8JvPZmNPAtKXk1v5X37cod5x67ChX6o22k5IDShbJZ4cjlI"
}
{
  "time": "2024-07-31 15:50:39.025331292",
  "data": "zEx5rPzy10ASbVRFIfyRV9B3YQ34cDvkmRcCWhUWBDwqrANpLJ"
}

With compression enabled, the output of redis-cli looks like the following:
$ redis-cli XRANGE test.stream - + COUNT 3
1) 1) "1722441173181340999-0"
   2) 1) "event"
      2) "\x1f\x8b\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xabVP*\xc9\xccMU\xb2RP2202\xd150\xd756T04\xb525\xb225\xd63\xb40460\xb7\xb4\xb4P\xd2QPJI,I\x04)4\xf0\xcfr\xf4\xf3JJt\x89\bw\r(L3t\xf6\nM\xce\x0e\xf6\xcb\xf2\x0cq\xf4\xae\n\r\xf44\xaeJ,5.6tK\xf1\xcb\x8d\n\xc8\b\x0fL2QR\xa8\x05\x00\xbe\x82\xa2\x8di\x00\x00\x00"
2) 1) "1722441174181899637-0"
   2) 1) "event"
      2) "\x1f\x8b\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xabVP*\xc9\xccMU\xb2RP2202\xd150\xd756T04\xb525\xb225\xd13\xb40\xb40\xb3\xb402P\xd2QPJI,I\x04)\xacp\xf7s\xf6\t.\xcb\xce1\x0ctv.M\x8e0\xadH\x0f\xc8\b\xc8w-6\xae,)0+-\xf4\xf1\xf6\xf5tw\xcaN\n\xf3\xca\xb2\xf4\xc9\b\bOOUR\xa8\x05\x00\x14\x8d\x80\x9di\x00\x00\x00"
3) 1) "1722441175182477580-0"
   2) 1) "event"
      2) "\x1f\x8b\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xabVP*\xc9\xccMU\xb2RP2202\xd150\xd756T04\xb525\xb225\xd53\xb4021\xb6045S\xd2QPJI,I\x04)\xf4\xc8\xf3\xc9\xf2\xca4\xf7\xcd5r\xact\xcc3s*\xf1\x0cO\x8b2\x0f\xb1tL/t\xf6\xcd*\n\r\xcb\x8f\bqO\xcf\xc8+\xf1/\r\xc8(\xf5\xcd2NQR\xa8\x05\x00\x12\x97Kai\x00\x00\x00"

We can no longer grep for "time", but I have found that I can use awk to print only every 3rd line:
$ redis-cli XRANGE test.stream - + COUNT 3 | awk 'NR % 3 == 0'
(L3t���MU�RP2202�50�56T04�25�25�3�0460���P�QPJI,I)4��r��JJtw
L2QR�����i
��VP*��MU�RP2202�50�56T04�25�25�3�0�0��02P�QPJI,I)�p�s� .��1
                                                            tv.M�0�H�w-6�,)0+-����tw�N
event

My idea was to then pipe this to gzip -d, but it doesn't work - gzip pukes with a crc error and length error
$ redis-cli XRANGE test.stream - + COUNT 3 | awk 'NR % 3 == 0' | gzip -d
{ "time": "2024-07-31 15:52:53.181307998", "data": "0OjANJbaDXWEPqf1CJPhWQb4" }
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error

I have tried lz4, lzma and zstd and more-or-less the same issues apply... how to pull out the payload and stream it "line by line" to a decompression utility.
Presumably because it is binary data it doesn't play nicely with piping and the notion of "line by line"?
Question:
Is there any way we can continue to use redis-cli to pull out stream contents and decompress it on the command line?
